# Checking the file size and type using php

Tags: php, html

My assignment is to make a php file for uploading files to a directory. The user should only be able to upload a file if the file size is less than 512kb and the file type is txt, zip or jpg. My code is not working properly as it ignores the output if file is not relevant and it also does not check the file type properly. Can anyone help please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Files</title>

</head>

<body>



<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="dat">
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
<div>(max. size: 512kb, Type: jpg,txt,zip)</div>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_FILES["dat"])){
    $file=$_FILES["dat"];
    $name=$file["name"];
    $size=$file["size"];
    $location=$file["tmp_name"];
    $location_file=$location . basename($name);


    if($size>512000 or $location_file!="txt" or $location_file!="zip" or $location_file!="jpg"){
        echo "The file is too big or the format is not correct...";
    }
    else{
        move_uploaded_file($location,"files/".$name);
    }
}

?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: My php is a bit rusty but for a start, I guess `$location_file` contains much more than just file extension, therefore comparing it with an extension will always return false. Did you even try debugging ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try to debug your uploaded file. Secondly don't rely on the name of the file since it can be spoofed easily.
tmp_name gives you the files temporary location, which will be a random string.
Your best option is to call `getimagesize` on tmp_name, for images, and `finfo_open` or `new finfo` for other file types to compare its mime type, you could also `explode` the name and use `end` which will give you an extension as well. maybe define an array of accepted extensions and use `in_array` to check if extension is valid.
Will provide example code after I get to a PC.

**LE:** as promised a more complex check with comments and security concepts

```
<?php
// you can make sure you have every variable set
// then procced further
if(
    isset(
        $_FILES['dat'], $_FILES['dat']['tmp_name'],
        $_FILES['dat']['name'], $_FILES['dat']['size'],
        $_FILES['dat']['error']
    )
){

    $accepted = array(
        'image/jpeg'      => 'jpg',
        'text/plain'      => 'txt',
        'application/zip' => 'zip',
    );
    $file      = $_FILES['dat'];
    $maxSize   = 512 * 1024; // 512 KB

    // check if any upload error occured
    if( UPLOAD_ERR_OK !== $file['error'] ){

        // http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php
        echo 'Upload error: ', $file['error'], '<br/>';

    // check if file size is bigger than $maxSize
    } elseif( $file['size'] > $maxSize ){
        // if filesize is bigger than upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini
        // script may timeout without any error
        // post_max_size and upload_max_filesize need to be high enough
        echo 'Error: File size is to big!<br/>';

    // can proceed further
    } else {

        // you will need to have the fileinfo enabled in php ini to use these
        $finfo    = finfo_open( FILEINFO_MIME );
        $mime     = finfo_file( $finfo, $file['tmp_name'] );
        // finfo may give you charset info as well
        // text/plain; charset=utf-8 or image/jpeg; charset=binary
        $mime     = array_shift( explode( ';', $mime ) );
        // change uploaded file name do to security reasons
        // google "php null char upload"
        // nice read http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/null-byte-injection-php/
        $filename = md5( time() . $file['name'] ) . '.';
        // if mime is accepted
        if( ! array_key_exists( $mime, $accepted ) /* or use isset: ! isset( $accepted[ $mime ] ) */ ){

            echo 'Error: Unsupported file type!<br/>';

        // you could check if file is image and check min-max width & height
        // for now move the uploaded file
        } elseif( ! @move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'], 'files/' . $filename . $accepted[ $mime ] ) ){

            echo 'Unable to save uploaded image to <strong>',
                htmlspecialchars( 'files/' . $filename . $accepted[ $mime ] ),
            '</strong>';

        } else {

            echo '<a href="files/', htmlspecialchars( $filename . $accepted[ $mime ] ), '" target="_blank">',
                htmlspecialchars( $filename . $accepted[ $mime ] ),
            '</a>';

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In html side

```
<input type="file" name="dat" accept=".txt, .zip, .jpg">
```

In server side :

```
<?php

$extension = array_pop(explode(".", $_FILES["dat"]["name"])); // return file extension

if(in_array($extension, array("zip", "txt", "jpg"))) // check if extension is valid
{
   if($_FILES['dat']['size'] > 512*1024) // check file size is above limit
   {
       echo "File size above limit";
   }
   else
   {
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES['dat']['tmp_name'],"files/".$_FILES['dat']['name']); // moving uploaded file
   }
}
else
{
  echo "Invalid file type";
}
```

Comment: make sure you don't use this code as it is in production, it`s prone to null byte injection, also just checking the extension is a bad thing, which can also lead to more security issues

Answer (score 0):

For format you will need to take out the extension from the file name like this:

```php
$explode = explode(".", $name);
$extension = $explode[sizeof($explode)-1]; //return "txt", "zip" or whatever

if(!in_array($extension, ["zip","txt", "jpg", "jpeg"])){
    //format error: not in correct format
} else {
    //format OK
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['dat']['tmp_name']);
    $allowed_mime_types = [
        "image/jpg",
        "image/jpeg",
        "application/zip",
        "plain/text"
    ];
    if(!in_array($mime, $allowed_mime_types)){
        //error format
    } else {
        //format OK

    }
}
```